# Android, difference between assets folder and internal storage

Tags: android, android-assets, internal-storage

Following are my understanding of them, and want to make sure it's correct.

Assets folder is a directory that I can place files so app can use. 
This is immutable folder.

Internal storage is a directory you are given when your app is installed.
You can mutate files under this directory.

If I maintain a read-write sqlite database, I will probably make it here under internal storage.
If I want to provide an initial database though, I would have to place it under the assets folder, and copy it when app is first run.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Content of Assets folder can't be changed at runtime.

Comment: when you have some fixed content like DB or fonts , you can put into assets folder.

Comment: why if i have existing sqlite (read only) database in assets i need to copy him to data/data.. external folder? why i cannot use it directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct. The difference between the Assets folder and the Internal Storage folder is that the Assets folder can't be changed at runtime. So the usage of internal storage and assets folder is as follows-

1) When one has fixed content like fonts,images,styles,string values,etc. put it into the assets folder.

2) If based on the programme the values must change based on the situation then save those values in the Internal Storage.

Comment: What kinds of values can be stored in internal storage?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you're right. The difference is that assets folder is read only folder. You can put your files there and use them in your app but if you need to change or modify them, you should copy them from assets to internal then do your works, so if you have static texts or fonts or files that needs nochange you can put them in assets folder but if you have database files you should copy ithem to internal.